# Unexplected results with Highcharts Heatmap

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

Following the examples on their website, I have (mostly!) succeeded in arriving at a hybrid of their two examples to show a heatmap

1. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap
2. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap-canvas

The only problem is, I seem to have introduced a ~30degree slant to the diagram such that each day's *column* is misaligned. I have posted an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/richardarnatt/LMSDX/

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
     align: 'left',
     x: 10,
  },
  tickInterval: 7*24*3600*1000
}
```

I have tried commenting out lines to see if it cancels out the aberration, but so far I have had very little success. If anyone has encountered this before I would be delighted to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Your JSFiddle has some external resource problems.

Comment: Really, how so? I just copied and pasted the link into another browser and all the CDN content loaded fine...

Comment: You are right. I must have some plugin blocking some content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the x-axis by not supplying proper dates. Try this:

```
$.each(perfData, function(i,v){
    var d = new Date(perfData[i][0]);
    var x = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate();
    var y = d.getHours();
    var z = perfData[i][1]/1000;
    d.setHours(0);
    var a = [d.getTime(),y,z];
    mapData.push(a);
});
```

The d.setHours(0) ensures that each point in the day starts at the same place on the x-axis. d.getTime() puts in a proper time in x rather than a string.

You also need to change the colSize to be one day:

```
colsize: 24*3600*1000,
```

and the tick interval to be 1 day:

```
tickInterval: 24*3600*1000
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Nptn/

Comment: Thank you! This is looking much, much better :)