# Plotting arrays of datetime x and y in highcharts heatmap

Tags: datetime, highcharts, timestamp, heatmap

According to the [highcharts Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cheatmap%3E.data) it should be possible to supply series data to a heatmap in the form [datetime, value], but every jsfiddle example I've seen uses the cartesian form of [x, y, value].

My datetime timestamps are unix time in milliseconds, so all of the required data is available, i.e. date, time and corresponding value, so there is no reason why highcharts should need this time-stamped data to be manipulated into an increasing index.

This guy's question seems to be the closest example I can find, but he himself reverts to using a workaround function 
[Unexplected results with Highcharts Heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936131/unexplected-results-with-highcharts-heatmap)

When I followed a similar approach (slightly different for me as I've got 15min intervals) Highcharts seems to interpret the unix timestamp for x-axis labelling correctly, but not for the tooltip or y-axis.

Surely there is a more sensible way of doing this?

Comment: your 'datetime' is just the x value. You still need a y value so the chart knows *where* to plot - then the actual value, so the chart knows *what* to plot. Since we don't know how you're doing this, we can't tell you if there's a more sensible way :)  Post a fiddle or at least your code.

Comment: That Docs link does not show that. The actual doc for series.heatmap is http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<heatmap>.data. This states it must be [x, y, value].

Comment: Thanks, got a working example, didn't relaise I needed to set the z-axis to datetime as well.http://jsfiddle.net/ciarancourtney/LMSDX/12/